# iOS: For implementing instruction overlay: need one branch of view hierarchy to be laid out before another branch is laid out

Tags: ios, uiview, uiview-hierarchy

I'm trying to implement an overlay to provide instructions to the user about the other views in an app. Here's a sketch of the view hierarchy:

```
SomeFullScreenContainerView
    FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView
        InstructionView
    FullScreenView
        MaybeSomeIntermediateViews
            ViewToProvideInstructionsFor
```

I need to position `InstructionView` relative to `ViewToProvideInstructionsFor`, but to do that, I need to be sure that the branch of the view hierarchy containing `ViewToProvideInstructionsFor` has been laid out so that I can refer to the frame of `ViewToProvideInstructionsFor` to set the frame of `InstructionView`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated**

A few ideas:

1. Use Auto Layout constraints and let the layout engine handle it.
2. Insert `FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView` into the view hierarchy after `FullScreenView` is completed.
3. Make `[FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView layoutSubviews]` a no-op until you set some flag indicating that `FullScreenView` is ready.
4. Use `setNeedsLayout` after `FullScreenView` is ready and don't worry about the first pass being incorrect.

**original**

```
[viewThatNeedsToBeLaidOut layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use layoutIfNeeded. The problem is when to do it. It seems that I can do [SomeFullScreenContainerView layoutIfNeeded] to guarantee that the FullScreenView branch is laid out; then I need to to call [FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView setNeedsLayout] and [FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView layoutIfNeeded] to lay out the FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView branch. However, the FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView branch may be laid out with the wrong info on the first pass.

Comment: I ended up doing something like (2) combined with a variation of (3). I made `[FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView layoutSubviews]` not layout `InstructionView` at all. Instead, `FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView` has a special `layoutInstructionView` method. In `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the view controller for `SomeFullScreenContainerView`, I first call `[SomeFullScreenContainerView layoutIfNeeded]` (which lays out `FullScreenView`), then `[FullScreenContainerOfInstructionView layoutInstructionView]`, and finally `[InstructionView layoutIfNeeded]`.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I had forgotten about this post and did something very similar to what you describe last week for a table view animation issue.